# Scraping a hiring website using python's requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm designing a scraping application using python, requests and BeautifulSoup4.

I decided to divide the logic into two classes:

- `Spider` : gets the base url containing a list of job offers and logs them into a SQL table `logs` .
- `Extractor`: it pulls the urls of job offers' posts from the `logs` table and it dumps them into json files (one by one).

I want to know how bad is the application design and how to improve it. and I'll appreciate some additional tips on how to improve my design skills (books, articles to read or courses to buy or follow + good python code to read ...)

Here is the `Spider`,

```py
import json
import os
import sqlite3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, UnicodeDammit
import requests

class Spider:

    def __init__(self, main_url='https://www.rekrute.com/offres-emploi-metiers-de-l-it.html'):
        self.main_url = main_url # first url to crowl
        self.next_url = None # next url to crowl
        self.links = [] # list of post links
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('log.db') # connect to database

# set self.response to main_url if it's the first round else set it to next_url
    def init_response(self):

        cookies = {
            'PHPSESSID': 'my_cookie_here',
            'PopUpHP': '1',
        }

        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0',
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        }

        if self.next_url is None:
            self.response = requests.get(self.main_url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
        else:
            headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.rekrute.com/offres-emploi-metiers-de-l-it.html'
            self.response = requests.post(self.next_url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

# extract the list of links from the page
    def parse_response(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response.text, 'html.parser')
        sections  = soup.find_all('li',class_='post-id')
        for s in sections:
            self.links.append(
                {
                    'id': s['id'],
                    'title': UnicodeDammit(s.h2.text.strip()).unicode_markup,
                    'link': s.h2.a['href'],
                    'status': 'pending'
                }
            )
        last_id = sections[-1].get('id')
        base_url = 'https://www.rekrute.com/rekrute/UserJobOffer/GetJobOfferPagination/last_id/'

        self.next_url = base_url + last_id

# save the posts into the database
    def save_logs(self):

        c = self.connection.cursor()
        for l in self.links:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO logs Values(?, ?, ?, ?)", ( l['id'], l['title'], l['link'], l['status']))

        """
        with open('logs.csv', 'a') as logf:
            if os.stat('logs.csv').st_size == 0:
                logf.write(','.join(self.links[0].keys())+'\n')
            for l in self.links:
                logf.write(','.join(l.values())+'\n')
        self.links = []
        """

    def crawl(self):
        # the crawling trigger
        i = 0
        print("Starting Crawling")
        while True:
            print("crowling {}".format(self.next_url))
            self.init_response()
            if self.response.text.strip() == '':
                print("Nothing to Crawl! Bye!")
                break
            self.parse_response()
            self.save_logs()
            print("round {} is done starting round {}:".format(i,i+1))
            i += 1
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```

Here is the Extractor

````py
import json
import re
import sqlite3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

class Extractor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://www.rekrute.com/'
        self.post_urls = []
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect('log.db')

# load urls from database
    def load_urls(self, limit):
        c = self.connection.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE status='pending' LIMIT ?", (limit,))
        return c.fetchall()

# get the page by url, and parse it (returns dict)
    def parse(self, post_id, post_url):
        urll = self.base_url+post_url
        response = requests.get(urll)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        infos = soup.find('div', class_='info').text
        infos = re.sub('\n\n','\n',re.sub('\r\n','',infos))
        infos = infos.split('\n')

        post_dict = {
            'id' : post_id
        }
        for i in infos:
            if i != '':
                item = i.strip().split(':')
                post_dict[item[0].strip()] = item[1].strip()

        return post_dict

# save post_dict in a json file 
    def to_json(self, post):
        filename = 'posts/post_'+ str(post.get('id'))+'.json'
        with open(filename, 'w') as ff:
           json.dump(post, ff, ensure_ascii=False)

# get all urls and parse the pages one by one, and save them to json files.
    def start_parsing(self):
        posts = self.load_urls(100)
        for p in posts:
            tmp_post = self.extract(p[0], p[2])
            self.to_json(tmp_post)

            c = self.connection.cursor()
            c.execute("UPDATE logs SET status=? WHERE post_id=?", ('saved',p[0]))
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()
```
````